# Output both ps and Date on one line, to a file?

Tags: debian, date, ps

I am building a rudimentary logging script, and want to capture the output of `ps up 12345`

So far I have:

```
DATE2=`date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S`
echo ${DATE2} >> $filename

ps up 12345 --no-headers >> $filename
```

This gives me the information I want, but on three lines (1=the date, 2=the output of ps 3=a blank line)

However, ideally I would like to capture these on one line. Is there a way to combine them (and ignore the blank line)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save ps output to variable, too, and write it using one echo or printf.

```
DATE2=`date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S`
PS_RESULT=`ps up 12345 --no-headers`

printf "%s: %s" "${DATE2}" "${PS_RESULT}" >> $filename
```

Side note, it might be useful to get accustomed to `$(command)` instead of `` `command` `` when you can use it, as this syntax can be nested.

Comment: OK cheers, that is useful to know.

Comment: And FYI using `echo` this would be `echo -n "${DATE2}" "${PS_RESULT}"` >> ${filename}

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to not print a newline at the end of the first string. You'll probably want a space instead.

```
echo -n "${DATE2} " >>"$filename"
```